# Why do these two python functions return different results?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

1-

```
 def fib1(n):
     a = 0
     b = 1
     while a < n:
        print b
        a = b
        b = a+b
```

2-

```
 def fib2(n):
     a, b = 0,1
     while a < n:
         print b
         a,b = b, b+a
```

On execution:

`fib1(10)` I got the wrong answer: `0 1 2 4 8`

`fib2(10)` I got the right answer: `0 1 1 2 3 5 8`

Comment: sorry i ment def :) typing error

Comment: Seen this exact same question posted here awhile ago. Where did the question come from ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In fib 1 
`a = b`
overwrites the value of `a`,

which means `a` is no longer the right value for the statement

`b = a+b`

However, in your second example both those things happen at the same time on the line `a,b = a, b+a` which means `a` is the right value still.

Comment: what i can't git it is, how those things  happen at the same time?, i guess in  both fib1() and fib2() a = b will overwrite the value of a with the new b = a+b.

Comment: The RHS happens before the assignment to the left hand side.

so B+A will be computed, then B will be computed, then b will be assigned to a + b, and a will be assigned to b

Comment: For example, when you say

b = a + b

the first thing that happens is that `a+b` is computed and stored somewhere tempory in memory. After that computation the value is moved in to be.

The same thing happens in this case

a,b = b, b+a

first, b+a is computed and stored somewhere temporary.

Then b is computed and stored somewhere temporary.

Finally b = the computed value of a+b)
and a = the computed value of b

Comment: finally got it, it's very helpful indeed, thanks :)
one last question, why the first returned value in fib2() is 0 ? i guess it should be 1.

Comment: In my experience running the code, it does not output a zero first.

my output of fib2(10) is 1 1 2 3 5 8 13

Answer (score 0):

here's a quick answer:

the basic difference is the way the values of `a` and `b` are reassigned.
In `fib1()`, you have

```
a = b
b = a + b
```

while in `fib2()`, you have

```
a, b = b, b + a
```

Now, these two looks equal statements but they are not.
Here's why:

In `fib2()`, you assign the values of the tuple `(b, b + a)` to the tuple `(a, b)`. Hence, reassignment of values are simultaneous.

However, with `fib1()`, you first assign value of `b` to `a` using `a = b` and then assign the value `a + b` to `b`. Since you have already changed value of `a`, you are in effect doing

```
b = a + b = b + b = 2b
```

In other words, you are doing `a, b = b, 2b` and that is why you are getting multiples of 2 rather than the fibonacci sequence.

Answer (score 0):

`fib1` contains a *classic* bug. It is in the same realm as that of swapping values of two variables. Think about how you would have done that in C or C++.

```
int a = 3;
int b = 5;
int temp;
temp = a; /* 3 */
a = b; /* 5 */
b = temp; /* 3, hence swapped */
```

There is a way to do without `temp`, although there are intermediate calculations involved. Now in Python, if you are **not** going to exploit the `tuple` unpacking feature, you have to involve a `temp` variable.

```
a = 3
b = 5
temp = a
a = b
b = temp
```

OR

```
a = 3
b = 5
a_ = (a+b)/2 - (a-b)/2 # 5.0
b_ = (a+b)/2 + (a-b)/2 # 3.0
```

Better use the tuple unpacking as in `fib2`.